# Cannot connect to GCP CloudSQL MSSQL using sqlalchemy-pytds

Tags: python, sql-server, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy

I have following code which saves dataframe to the place where connector is watching

```py
def fill_test_data(connector_class, config) -> tuple[AbstractConnector, pd.DataFrame]:
  """Writes pandas dataframe as a table to the database"""
  connector, df = prepare_test_data(connector_class, config)

  with connector as con:
    df.to_sql(name=config.get("db_table"), con=con, index=False, if_exists="replace")

  return connector, df
```

Connector has this methods to be able to connect to cloud sql database

```py
  def __get_connection(self) -> Any:
    """Get connection to GCP Cloud SQL database"""
    decoded_creds = base64.b64decode(self.params["db_creds_base64"].encode()).decode()
    db_creds = json.loads(decoded_creds)
    creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(db_creds)
    return Connector(credentials=creds).connect(
      instance_connection_string=self.params["db_instance"],
      driver=self.params["db_driver"],
      user=self.params["db_user"],
      password=self.params["db_pass"],
      db=self.params["db_name"],
      ip_type=IPTypes.PUBLIC
    )

  def _make_engine(self) -> sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:
    """Make engine for db"""
    db_type = self.params["db_type"]
    db_driver = self.params["db_driver"]
    suffix_dns: str = ""
    # exceptional case when we use mssql server
    if db_driver == CloudSQLDriverEnum.SQLSERVER:
      suffix_dns = "localhost"
    return sqlalchemy.create_engine(
      url=f"{db_type}+{db_driver}://{suffix_dns}", creator=self.__get_connection
    )
```

```py
def cloud_sql_mssql() -> tuple[CloudSQLConnector, pd.DataFrame]:
app-test_1  |       """Produce cloud sql connector and test df"""
app-test_1  |       table_name = "test_table"
app-test_1  |       creds = json.dumps(json.load(open("cred.json", "r")))
app-test_1  |       config = {
app-test_1  |         "type": "cloudsql",
app-test_1  |         "db_instance": f"{conf.CSQL_PROJECT}:{conf.CSQL_REGION}:{conf.CSQL_MSSQL_INSTANCE}",
app-test_1  |         "db_type": CloudSQLTypeEnum.SQLSERVER,
app-test_1  |         "db_user": conf.CSQL_USER,
app-test_1  |         "db_pass": conf.CSQL_PASS,
app-test_1  |         "db_name": conf.CSQL_DATABASE,
app-test_1  |         "db_table": table_name,
app-test_1  |         "db_driver": CloudSQLDriverEnum.SQLSERVER,
app-test_1  |         "db_creds_base64": base64.b64encode(creds.encode()).decode(),
app-test_1  |       }
app-test_1  | >     connector, df = fill_test_data(CloudSQLConnector, config)
app-test_1  | 
app-test_1  | wand/sneakpeek/test/fixtures/cloud_sql_fixture.py:75: 
app-test_1  | _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
app-test_1  | wand/sneakpeek/test/fixtures/utils.py:12: in fill_test_data
app-test_1  |     with connector as con:
app-test_1  | wand/shared/models/connector.py:39: in __enter__
app-test_1  |     self._connection = engine.connect()
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:3197: in connect
app-test_1  |     return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:96: in __init__
app-test_1  |     else engine.raw_connection()
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:3276: in raw_connection
app-test_1  |     return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:3243: in _wrap_pool_connect
app-test_1  |     return fn()
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:310: in connect
app-test_1  |     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:868: in _checkout
app-test_1  |     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:476: in checkout
app-test_1  |     rec = pool._do_get()
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py:146: in _do_get
app-test_1  |     self._dec_overflow()
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py:70: in __exit__
app-test_1  |     compat.raise_(
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py:207: in raise_
app-test_1  |     raise exception
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py:143: in _do_get
app-test_1  |     return self._create_connection()
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:256: in _create_connection
app-test_1  |     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:371: in __init__
app-test_1  |     self.__connect()
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:666: in __connect
app-test_1  |     pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py:70: in __exit__
app-test_1  |     compat.raise_(
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py:207: in raise_
app-test_1  |     raise exception
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:661: in __connect
app-test_1  |     self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py:241: in <lambda>
app-test_1  |     return lambda crec: creator()
app-test_1  | wand/shared/models/connector.py:100: in __get_connection
app-test_1  |     return Connector(credentials=creds).connect(
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/connector.py:146: in connect
app-test_1  |     return connect_task.result()
app-test_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py:446: in result
app-test_1  |     return self.__get_result()
app-test_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py:391: in __get_result
app-test_1  |     raise self._exception
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/connector.py:245: in connect_async
app-test_1  |     raise (e)
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/connector.py:239: in connect_async
app-test_1  |     return await asyncio.wait_for(get_connection(), timeout)
app-test_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py:479: in wait_for
app-test_1  |     return fut.result()
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/connector.py:235: in get_connection
app-test_1  |     return await self._loop.run_in_executor(None, connect_partial)
app-test_1  | /usr/local/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py:58: in run
app-test_1  |     result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/pytds.py:76: in connect
app-test_1  |     return pytds.connect(
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytds/__init__.py:1345: in connect
app-test_1  |     conn._open(sock=sock)
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytds/__init__.py:372: in _open
app-test_1  |     self._try_open(timeout=retry_time, sock=sock)
app-test_1  | /venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytds/__init__.py:354: in _try_open
app-test_1  |     self._connect(host=host, port=port, instance=instance, timeout=timeout, sock=sock)
app-test_1  | _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
app-test_1  | 
app-test_1  | self = <pytds.Connection object at 0xffff98249970>, host = '34.140.48.128'
app-test_1  | port = 1433, instance = '', timeout = 2.4
app-test_1  | sock = <ssl.SSLSocket [closed] fd=-1, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6>
app-test_1  | 
app-test_1  |     def _connect(self, host, port, instance, timeout, sock=None):
app-test_1  |         login = self._login
app-test_1  |     
app-test_1  |         try:
app-test_1  |             login.server_name = host
app-test_1  |             login.instance_name = instance
app-test_1  |             port = _resolve_instance_port(
app-test_1  |                 host,
app-test_1  |                 port,
app-test_1  |                 instance,
app-test_1  |                 timeout=timeout)
app-test_1  |             if not sock:
app-test_1  |                 logger.info('Opening socket to %s:%d', host, port)
app-test_1  |                 sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
app-test_1  |         except Exception as e:
app-test_1  |             raise LoginError("Cannot connect to server '{0}': {1}".format(host, e), e)
app-test_1  |     
app-test_1  | >       sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
app-test_1  | E       OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

It gives me this traceback and I don't know what to do. I haven't found any information in google and **sqlalchemy-tds**. Looks like it's a bug in **pytds** library, but I haven't found a solution for it

Comment: does your `db_user` database user have appropriate permissions to read/write to the database `db_name`? If you are using the `sqlserver` root user then you should be fine but if you are using a different user you will need to grant them the appropriate permissions on the database. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/users#alerts-tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common reason for the `OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor` error with **pytds** is that the `db_user` does not have the appropriate read/write permissions granted on the `db_name` (database) that you are trying to connect to.

If you are using the `sqlserver` root user then you should be fine but if you are using a different user you will need to grant them the appropriate permissions on the database. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/users#alerts-tips

The `OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor` is a not very helpful error and may likely still be bug in the **pytds**. In the meantime hopefully the permissions fix you from seeing the error.

Comment: Yes, that was the solution. Thanks!